# MVC5 Creating a Form for a complex Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-5

I will be presenting my users a form to fill out a form to get some quotes.  There will be a series of objects (~15 or so) that I want to present as check boxes. The issue is, I don't want to hardcode in 15 bools, I want them to be dynamically built on a per-user basis. So a simplified version of the model I came up with would look something like this:

```
public class InqueryViewModel
{
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Option> AdvancedOptions { get; set; }
}

public class Option
{
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is, I can't figure out how to bind the AdvancedOptions. I tried this:

```
@foreach (var option in Model.AdvancedOptions)
{
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => option.Selected)
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            @option.Type
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    </div>
}
```

But that doesn't work. I'm pretty new to trying to use front-end forms with MVC, so I may just be going about this the wrong way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125809/aspnet-mvc-3-html-editorfor-a-subcollection-of-my-model-in-a-template, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756927/editorfor-collection-of-items-in-my-model

Comment: Do you have value set for `Model.AdvancedOptions`? Or is it null or empty?

Comment: Yes, I populate those before it's sent to the View.

Comment: Place a debugger (press f9) on that line `var option in Model.AdvancedOptions` and see what was set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to model bind to a list. The easiest way to achieve this is to change your view model to use an `IList<Option>` and then do the following:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.AdvancedOptions.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.AdvancedOptions[i].Selected)
}
```

See [Phil Haacks post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) about binding to collections for more information

Comment: Oops, I may have spoken too soon. When the `AdvancedOptions` post back, they've their `Type` property is now null. Seems that checkbox isn't preserving the data.

Comment: You will need a hidden input to post back the type `@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.AdvancedOptions[i].Type)`